# Prove $A\in M(3\times 3, \mathbb{R})$ is real upper-triangular or complex-diagonal w/out Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this problem while tutoring.  Its trivial if you use Jordan canonical form.

If $A$ is a $3\times 3$ real matrix, show that $A$ is similar (in    $M(3\times 3,\mathbb{C})$) to a complex diagonal matrix or a real upper triangular matrix.

Well, ok, $A$ has a real eigenvalue.  If it only has one real eigenvalue, the others are distinct, so $A$ is diagonilizable over $\mathbb{C}$. It can't have just two real eigenvalues. What if it has 3? If they're distinct its diagonalizable in $\mathbb{R}$. If 2 are the same, and the other is different, its upper triangular in $\mathbb{R}$.

But what if it has a real eigenvalue of algebraic multiplicity 3? Is there some elementary or geometric argument here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ has three real eigenvalue $a,b,c$. Pick a corresponding and extend it to a basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Then there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=\pmatrix{a&\ast\\ 0&B}$, where the two eigenvalues of $B$ are $b$ and $c$. Now it suffices to show that $B$ is similar to a real upper triangular matrix, but that is easy if you play the same trick recursively.

Comment: Sorry, why are b and c eigenvalues of B?

Comment: @Plinytheill Because $bI-A$ and $cI-A$ are singular.

Comment: niice. thanks.!

Comment: I preferred your previous comment. was there something wrong with it?

Comment: the outstanding case is where a=b=c

Comment: and in that case $bI-A$ singular doesn't imply $bI - B$ is singular

Comment: but I think your deleted comment settled it, so ill just put it down here, if thats ok: the characteristic polynomial of A is $(a-\lambda)$ times the characteristic polynomial of B, so the latter is $(a-\lambda)(c-\lambda)$.

Comment: @Plinytheill You're right. I've underestimated the simplicity of this approach. It can be rescued by a continuity argument or perhaps some generalised eigenspace argument, but the determinantal approach may be simpler.